# Codeigniter File upload not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

i've a problem with uploading files to a 'temp' folder.
this is mij code to upload te file

```
//GET RANDOM STRING FOR TEMP FOLDER ATTACHMENT
    $randompath = $this->generateRandomString(20);
    $config['upload_path'] = "./include/upload/temps/$randompath/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|tiff';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;

    $fullpath = $config['upload_path'] . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('attachment'))
    {
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'Attachment',
            'value'  => $fullpath
        );

        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        //return $fullpath;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

i hope anyone can help me out with this.
folder permissions are 755
also the cookie is not set by the code below

Comment: what kind of problem? does it produce any error log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload folder **chmod** `777` and be a fixed location example

`$config['upload_path'] = './upload/temp/'`.

To be able to get the uploaded data place some thing like.

`$variable = $this->upload->data();` In the success part of form.

Then you can do this `$variable['full_path']`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries

Also I see you do not have `$this->upload->initialize($config);` you need that do make config work, as said in user guide.

```
$file_upload = $this->upload->data();

$fullpath = $file_upload['full_path']
$filename = $file_upload['file_name']
```

so would be  `$fullpath = $file_upload['full_path']`

```
$config['upload_path'] = "./include/upload/temps";
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|tiff';
$config['max_size'] = '2048';
$config['max_width'] = '0';
$config['max_height'] = '0';
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ($this->upload->do_upload('attachment') == TRUE) {

    $file_upload = $this->upload->data();

    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'Attachment',
        'value'  => $file_upload['full_path']
    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

    $this->load->view('upload_success');

} else {

    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping i figured out that the random folder never was created so the files never had a existing directory anyway thanks for trying